# Why doesn't this method work inside another method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, selector

I have this HTML table:

```
<table id="languages" border="0" cellspacing="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Language</th>
      <th>Type</th>
      <th>Invented</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Java</td>
      <td>Static</td>
      <td>1995</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ruby</td>
      <td>Dynamic</td>
      <td>1993</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Smalltalk</td>
      <td>Dynamic</td>
      <td>1972</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>C++</td>
      <td>Static</td>
      <td>1983</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

When I run this JavaScript:

```
alert($('td').index($('td:contains(C++)')))
```

I get a pop up saying `9`, which is what I would expect.

And when I run this: `alert($('td:eq(9)').text())`, the pop up says `C++`, again same as what one would expect. But if I try to put the first function/selection instead of hard coding `9` in the second selector, like this...

```
alert($('td:eq($('td').index($('td:contains(C++)')))').text())
// just replacing the hard coded 9 with the first selector, as it gives a value of 9
```

...nothing happens. I don't get any pop up saying `C++`, which is what one would expect, I don't get any pop up for that matter. Can anyone please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just a point, Google Chrome's Developer Tools is *brilliant* for debugging things like this

Comment: Note that (now that I've formatted your code properly) Stack Overflow applies colour-highlighting to your JS syntax that makes it more obvious that your string literals aren't being concatentated together properly - that is, this is a basic JavaScript syntax error, not a problem with the jQuery methods you're using.

Comment: @nnnnnn
Yeah, it does comes out now with the syntax highlighted by SO... couldn't find it while I was working though!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you aren't escaping the single quotes in the inner selector, so you're effectively exiting the string at that point, which is throwing an error. Change this:

```
alert($('td:eq($('td').index($('td:contains(C++)')))').text())
```

To this:

```
alert($('td:eq(' + $('td').index($('td:contains(C++)')) + ')').text())
```

Comment: No problem! What editor do you use? Notepad++, SublimeText, and many more have syntax highlighting built in which makes these things much easier to spot! :)

Answer (score 1):

The below should work:

```
alert($('td:eq('+$('td').index($('td:contains(C++)'))+')').text())
```